# On button click it should scroll to top in salesforce1 with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, app

```
    async ScrollToTop() {
        var scrollOptions = {
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        }
        window.scroll(scrollOptions);
    }
```

This works on PC but not working on IPAD in salesforce1 app. 
How can i do it?

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229742/javascript-window-scroll-behavior-smooth-not-working-in-safari

Answer (score 0):

You can try :
this.template.querySelector('.scrollCls').scrollIntoView();

where "scrollCls" would be the class of div element of the LWC